# How to use TouchableHighlight as a reusable component

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a reusable button in ReactNative. To do this, I have created a stateless component which returns a TouchableHighlight component configurable through props passed in to the reusable component.

OutlineButton.js

```
const OutlineButton = ({color, text, onClick}) => {
  let buttonStyles = (
    color ?
      _.assign({}, StyleSheet.flatten(styles.button), {borderColor: color}) :
      styles.button
  )

  return (
    <TouchableHighlight style={buttonStyles} onPress={onClick}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  )
};
```

CategoryButton.js

```
import OutlineBtn from '../buttons/outlineButton.js'
const CategoryButton = ({merchant}) => (
    let text = merchant ? merchant.category : '';
  <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
    <OutlineBtn
      color="red"
      text={text.split('_').join(' ')} />
  </View>
);
```

Transaction.js(Active Page)

```
import Category from '../components/singleTransaction/categoryButton.js'
class Transaction extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {}
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        this.props.getTransaction(this.props.transactionId);
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <Category ref="touchbtn" merchant={this.state.merchant} />
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}
```

However when I try to use this component I get a warning `Touchable child must either be native or forward setNativeProps to a native component`

What am I doing wrong?

**Note:** I am aware of the `setNativeProps()` method that needs to be passed down if a `TouchableHighlight` has a child that is not a native component (e.g. `<View>` or `<Text>`). But in my case the child of `TouchableHighlight` is indeed a native component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from what I've discovered, this is a limitation of stateless functional components. :(

Namely, while your function is returning a native component...it is not actually a native component itself, when used. In cases where I've wanted to use a functional native component inside a `<Touchable...>`, my options have been to:

- wrap the stateless component in a `<View>` in the caller, which is a native component
- rewrite the stateless functional component as a class-based component instead (ie, `extends React.Component`)

Comment: Yeah I had to revert to using a `Class` component in order to get it working too. But what are the technical reason for why I can't use a stateless component?

Answer (score 1):

As I wanted to use a stateless component inside of a TouchableHighlight, my only option was to wrap the stateless component in a View:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => { this._pressRow(); }} >
    <View>
         <StatelessItem data={_data}/>
    </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Answer (score 0):

is too late but using Stateless Component you could declare event into your own component, example:

```
const OutlineButton = (props) => {
  const navigationButton_OnClick = (event) => {
    /* Do something */
  };

  return(
    <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='rgba(0,0,0,0)' onPress={navigationButton_OnClick}>
       /* Do something */
    </TouchableHighlight>
  )  
};
```